# Clicking class button on website

Tags: c#

I have the following code for a webpage;

```
<div class="toolbox">
<div class="toolboxNest" align="left">
<div class="clear"> </div>
<div class="gap"> </div>
<label for="j_username">
<input id="j_username" type="text" name="j_username">
<div class="clear"> </div>
<div class="gap"> </div>
<label for="j_password">
<input id="j_password" type="password" name="j_password">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="gap"></div>
<div align="center">
<input class="formButtonGreen" type="submit" value="Login">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="gap"></div>
<div class="infoText">
```

I am able to click and enter text for the username and password, but I cant work out how to press the submit button, if it were just an element then that would be fine, but it's in a class and I'm unsure how to do it.

This is my code...

```
var x = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("j_username");
  x[0].InnerText = "xxxxx";
  var y = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("j_password");
  y[0].InnerText = "xxxxxxxx";

//This part is not working....
 var s = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("formButtonGreen");
  s[0].InvokeMember("click");
```

Any one got any ideas?

Please note: I don't own the website so can't make changes to code behind webpage...

Thanks,

David

Comment: Why can't you give the button an ID as well?

Comment: Why do you specifically want to click a form submit button from your code behind?

Comment: I don't own the website I'm trying to control from code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("input")` which should help you get the button element and later you can use `InvokeMember("click")` on that element.

This will return a collection of matching elements, so if there are more than one you will have to identify it from the attributes by looping over it and then trigger for the one you need.

Comment: When i do this, it is submitting the form, but I am getting an error: "Invalid direct reference to form login page."

Comment: Not sure but maybe it needs some other thing(maybe url) to load once authenticated, Can you login using a normal browser ?

Comment: you mean you access the login page directly and it has no params/querystring indicating redirects ?

Comment: I can't see that, I am accessing the page directly and can't see the code behind. Is there no way I can find the position of the button on the screen, position the mouse and click it? Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking the button, just submit the form itself.

jQuery wise, this is:

```
$("#my_form").submit();
```

Or you coulkd use any other means to select that Form. By class, parent element, tag name, ...